# what is COP3 protocol?

Tags: network-programming, protocols

I'm working on a file transfer application. Can anybody send me details about COP3 protocol which I got at http://www.tvtechnology.com/article/19320 link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems COP3 [is the group](http://www.videoservicesforum.org/COP3_Standardization.shtml) which made SMTPE 2022.